# Adding views in Android from Java source

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that requires the user to either increase or decrease the number of edit texts during application run-time (eg, in the default Android contacts app).

Someone please assist with some Java source code

Answer (score 3):

Assume we have a container defined in an xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Now we can do this:

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
container.addView(editText);
```

**Note:** The container doesn't even have to be defined via xml. We can also create the container dynamically and use `setContentView`. It also does **not** have to be the root `ViewGroup` of your layout.